# Reacotron's displaying actions before sagas

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga, reactotron

I just downloaded Reactotron, but found a pretty strange error(?).

To be able to understand it I will describe my process flow:

```
1.) App is starting
2.) I dispatch a ON_START_APP
3.) I will takeEvery ON_START_APP in a saga
4.) ON_START_APP will put (saga) a START_FETCH_RATES
5.) START_FETCH_RATES will put a FETCH_RATES_FAIL
```

But for some reason the ACTION is displayed before the SAGA is PUTTING IT IN.

[image]

Quite strange, right?
Is this how it's should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the expected behavior. Reactotron displays saga information once the forked task is completed. Since your `put` effect is executed before the the saga is actually complete, you should see the action before you see saga details.

Comment: Ahh this absolutely make
Thanks for making it clear! :)